# Section background image not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have write the following code to make a  have a background image. It's working on Chrome and Internet Explorer but it's not shown in firefox.

```html
<style type="text/css">
#profile{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-size: cover;   
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/6242932/1483907177/1500x500);

}

</style>
 <section id="profile" class="img-responsive">
```

I am using twitter bootstrap, someone can help?

This is when I inspect element in firefox it shows

```
#profile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    Getting a error in this part in blockquote*
```

> background-size: cover;
>           -webkit-background-size: cover;
>           -moz-background-size: cover;
>           background-size: cover;
>           -o-background-size: cover;

*
        background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/6242932/1483907177/1500x500");
    }

The blockquote part is shown with a line in the text like the  tag text deleted

Comment: I can see it in firefox (In the code snippet). Can you give us a reproducible issue?

Comment: When you inspect the section in Firefox , are there any background CSS rules striked off ? Can you post a screenshot of the inpect tool for the section.

Comment: It's just open stack overflow in firefox and run code snippet, it works on chome and ie but not in firefox the image is not shown

Comment: I updated the question the blockquote part is Shows with a line like the <del> tag text deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution the problem was **adblock** blocking the background image

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Mozilla Develop Network's article on background-size property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

I'm no expert at this, so I'm sure the resource can better articulate the answer than I can. Here is a note that may help you though:

*If the value of this property is not set in a background shorthand property that is applied to the element after the background-size CSS property, the value of this property is then reset to its initial value by the shorthand property.*

Perhaps it seems that your value is not taking hold because some property or value still needs to be defined in your code. Sorry if this wasn't too clear, just trying to point you in the right direction!

-Tyler

Answer (score 1):

I can see in firefox and in another browser also. Just increase size of height from 100px to 500px and width to 1500px or as per your requirement.